# While loop comparing size instead of amount

Tags: c++, while-loop, std

I am trying to create a while loop that takes 'x' amount of integers the user wants (`total`), and then keep looping until the user inputs all of the integers. When the user inputs the `total`, the while loop has a comparison but it doesn't work (I'm aware of this, but I don't know how to fix it). If the `total` is bigger than `numbers`, it exits the loop. I want it to loop until the chosen number (by the user) of integers is inputted!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> //for accumulate


int sumUpTo(const std::vector<int>& vec, const std::size_t total) //const prevents parameters to not be modified in function.
{
    if (total > vec.size())
        return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);

    return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + total, 0);
}


int main() {

    
    std::vector <int> storage;
    int total = 0, numbers = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter the amount of numbers you want to input\n";
    std::cin >> total;
    std::cout << "Now enter your numbers\n";
    std::cin >> numbers;
    
    while (numbers < total) {
        std::cin >> numbers;


            storage.push_back(numbers); //takes user input (numbers) and pushes them into the vector (storage).
    }

    sumUpTo(storage, total);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `for` loop that loops `total` times? Also, your first number is discarded.

Comment: It seems that you are a beginner. You have two ways to do this. The first way would be to  create a third variable and then you increase the variable with 1 every iteration in your loop. Then check this variable against total. The "correct" way would be, to check the size() of the vector, that is an in-build function of the vector container

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If you read the next sentence I said there

Comment: The `const` on the second argument of `sumUpTo()` (i.e. `const std::size_t total`) is unnecessary, since any changes of `total` will be invisible to the caller, and there is no modification of `total` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As @Quimby suggested, use a for-loop. Also, you call `std::cin` twice for the first number so I have removed it. In comments I added the "while-loop" solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> //for accumulate


int sumUpTo(const std::vector<int>& vec, const std::size_t total) //const prevents parameters to not be modified in function.
{
    if (total > vec.size())
        return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);

    return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + total, 0);
}


int main() {

    
    std::vector <int> storage;
    int total = 0, numbers = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter the amount of numbers you want to input\n";
    std::cin >> total;
    std::cout << "Now enter your numbers\n";
    
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> numbers;
        storage.push_back(numbers); //takes user input (numbers) and pushes them into the vector (storage).
    }

    //while (total > storage.size())
    //{
    //    std::cin >> numbers;
    //    storage.push_back(numbers); //takes user input (numbers) and pushes them 
    //into 
    //the vector (storage).
    //}

    auto sum = sumUpTo(storage, total);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also `storage.reserve(total)` will not be a bad idea!